# I’m finally logged into Worldbuilding.SE, now how do I get my old accounts back?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Thanks guys, I’m finally I full fledged member of this Stack Exchange. Willk, Alexander JBH thanks for the help. Now how do I round up all the other DTs?

Comment: Read [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @nzaman: What if you don’t remember the email you used

Comment: The odds of other non-registered accounts named "DT Cooper" feel low to me.  And to whomever downvoted this answer.  Jeez!  Vote to migrate to Meta and be kind.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, use the contact form in @nzaman's link to explain to the Powers That Be what's going on and why the other accounts remained unregistered.  I'm positive they've had to work through this before.  If necessary, hunt down previous quetsions so you can giv the PTB links to the affected accounts.

Comment: @JBH: So, I don’t remember the emails I put because they were all random fakes. So, how can I merge my accounts

Comment: @JBH: Hey friend, how do you get another profiles URL. I’m not used to this webs design

Comment: You usually ask about your Qualians.  Search the WB site for "Qualians".  I think questions involving them are probably all from your various incarnations.  Click on the name and there is the account.  That Rogan Kennedy one has accumulated a fair bit of rep.  Happy consolidating!

Comment: @Willk: How do I get the 5 numbers needed though. I keep entering it in wrong. Uggggh, my computer is bugging out. Dude, can you DT Cooper URL so I can write it manually

Comment: Find account.  Click on name.  Go to top of browser bar and copy URL.  Here is the urls of the ones I think are yours : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/51013/dt-cooper.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/53268/dt-cooper. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/50803/talos-6 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/53120/daluk https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52591/v-sychem

Comment: @Willk: Hey I also had this account named Bryan, and on it I asked the question “How would people in the 17th century react to modern day clothing” it has 68 upvotes, and 7 answers. Can you please send the link to it as well. Sorry for the inconvenience, but you’d really helping a guy out. My computer is buffering a lot.

Comment: Here is that one and one more I think ia yours:  worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/47428/bryan 
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48767/canyon-runner

Comment: @Willk: Hey, Willk I have a question. If I want to merge two accounts, but only have access to one account, how does that work?

Comment: @JBH: I’m still confused. How do I merge without knowing the emails?

Comment: The admins simply need references, be they email addresses or links to example posts for each account or the user numbers.  @Willk has provided all of these.  Send those via the contact form and the admins can deal with this.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need help from SE (moderators can't merge accounts); see [this help topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for more about that.  If you don't have profile links or email addresses for all your past accounts, try searching the site to find some of your past questions (with luck, you remember enough about what you've asked to do this) and include those links with your request.  If you have any other identifying information, include that too.

For example, a comment points out that you often ask about "Qualians".  A [search on main for questions containing that word](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=Qualians+is%3Aq) produces several results.  If any of those are you, you can right-click on a user name under a question to copy the URL to your clipboard and, from there, into your message to SE.

The team has to balance between helping you bring all your accounts together, on the one hand, and avoiding merging an account that really belongs to somebody else, on the other.  Since, if you used bogus email addresses, they can't contact the other accounts to ask for confirmation, you're going to have to supply enough information to be persuasive.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I still can’t get my past URLs though

Comment: @DTCooper see my edit.

Comment: What if I don’t know the email

Comment: @DTCooper as I said, you will need to contact SE for help.  Tell them what you know and ask them if they can help you.  We cannot.